# Is it possible to pass environment variables from the Elastic Beanstalk Console to a React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm not running my React app on node locally. I just deployed it directly to Elastic Beanstalk, with a Node environment. When I set the environment variables, for example in EB config software env variables, and I try to console log process.env, it logs

```
{NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: "", WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined, WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined, …}
FAST_REFRESH: true
NODE_ENV: "development"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined
```

and none of my env variables are to be found.